# How do I resolve nested promises in an object

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Code:

```
async function main() {
  const arr = [];
  symbols.forEach((symbol) => {
    const record = {
      [symbol]: {
        quote: priceQuote(token, symbol),
        history: makePriceHistoryRequest(token, symbol, slow * 2),
      }
    }
    arr.push(record);
  })
    return arr;
}
```

I call main as follows:

```
main().then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
```

It returns `quote` and `history` as `Promise`. How can I get into nested pending promise?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't get your point. If you are calling main then which promise is pending according to your code?

Comment: Start by [not using `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). Instead, create an array of promises, then `Promise.all` them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `quote` and `history` are promises it means that `priceQuote` and `makePriceHistoryRequest` are functions that return promises, in this case, you need to make the callback that iterates them async, not the wrapper:

```
 function main() {
   return Promise.all(symbols.map(async (symbol) => {
     const record = {
      [symbol]: {
        quote: await priceQuote(token, symbol),
        history: await makePriceHistoryRequest(token, symbol, slow * 2),
      }
    }
    return record
  })  
}

main().then(value => console.log(value) )
```

Comment: Wow Cesare you're a genius. How do people get so good?  I'm just starting out self-teaching...

Comment: Just be patient. apply every day reading and writing a lot of code, it's just a matter of time and study!